# How to pre-processing data of a game - k-means

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have a table of users' scores like this:

```
user_id  score duration_of_per_play  start_date
  1        56    313                 2018-01-09
  2        14    560                 2018-08-01
  1        56    113                 2018-01-09
  4        14    340                 2018-08-01
....
```

now I want to use `k-means` algorithm the to cluster of users.
just I know that I haven't `Missing Values` and `outliers`.

but I don't know:

1. what is the next step?
2. do I need to `centering` data?

I have 42,000 records of this game. I want to cluster users depending on `score`s and `duration_of_per_play`.

Comment: You _do_ or _don't_ have outliers and/or missing values?

Comment: Create a vector of features (maybe a single row in there) and stuff it into a [k-means implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). The estimated means (which are attributes to the KMeans class) yield your result.
Note 1: No, you do not need to center your data.
Note 2: Check if this really fits your needs.

Comment: @Shlomif thanks for your comment, I do pre-processing for outliers and I haven't any missing values because I collected by these record's from my API and all Validation is done.

Answer (score 1):

K-means does not need pre-centering per-se, but you *will* gain from normalizing the data due to different scale of the features you're using.
Thus I recommend subtracting the mean and dividing by the STD (per-axis of course) and then just using one of many k-mean implementations.
I'd also read about k-means and the different options regarding choosing the number of clusters, dealing with outliers, etc. but that's not the "next step" as you asked.
Good luck!

---

This is a good implementation you can start with: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: Yes. But again, some pre-processing can help. Does my answer help?